# Can't revert a Loggable entity because of a Doctrine repository error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, gedmo-loggable

I want to revert an entity:

```php
// use Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry;
//...
$repo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(LogEntry::class);
$repo->revert($pizza, 1);
// ...
```

But I get an error:

> The class 'Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

I think it's a Doctrine problem, here is my `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` file:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '16'

        profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
        use_savepoints: true
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
        report_fields_where_declared: true
        validate_xml_mapping: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                type: attribute
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        filters:
            # soft deletion
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
        controller_resolver:
            auto_mapping: false

when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            proxy_dir: '%kernel.build_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system
```

Versions:

- Symfony 6.4
- Doctrine orm 2.19.3
- Doctrine bundle 2.12
- Doctrine extension bundle 1.11.0

Is there a configuration I must change?